# JAVA split text from file and convert to message

Tags: java, split

i created a message class (message has body,sender, address all strings)
i have a text file that looks like this:
From: sender
To: adreess
message body

(the fields are sperated with new line)

i need to create an array of messages from that text file

what is the best way to do it ? (i try to do it using split but had some problems)

Comment: Use BufferedFileReader  readLine() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem clearly, you have multiple messages in one file and a message is on 3 lines:

- From
- To
- Body

You can then do it like that:

```
public List<Message> getMessages(String fileName) throws IOException {
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String from;
        String to;
        String body;
        Message message;
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i += 3) {
            from = lines.get(i);
            to = lines.get(i + 1);
            body = lines.get(i + 2);
            message = new Message(from, to, body);
            messages.add(message);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return messages;
}
```

Here, you iterate through your messages file which you pass the filename in the parameters, and you increase your line counter of 3 at each iteration, so you can simply get every data you want (from, to and body).

If this code sample is not enough, you can use split() on from, to and body to extract the value only:

```
String fromValue = from.split(": ")[1]
```

NB: The message class used here is like that:

```
public class Message {

    private String from;

    private String to;

    private String body;

    public Message(String from, String to, String body) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If split function is not working fine, you can use a StringTokenizer. The string tokenizer class allows an application to break a string into tokens. The set of delimiters (the characters that separate tokens) may be specified either at creation time or on a per-token basis. Below you can find an example:

```
String message = "From: sender\nTo: adress message\nbody";
System.out.println(message);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message, "\n");

while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  System.out.print("[" + st.nextToken() + "]");
}
```